# Do music files on /sdcard go into apk?

Tags: android, audio, export, apk

I have an application that has been exported to an apk. I have stored some `.wav` music files on `/sdcard/audio` that are absolutely essential to the application. My question is this:

1. How do I export the wav files and make sure that they are present on the apk? When I export the project, the size of the apk is something like 23kB. It seems that I should have had the wav files somewhere else, in some other directory. I had added the files to /sdcard/audio by using mkdir + push commands in the `adb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those type of files should be in `/res/raw`.
Files in the sdcard will not be pushed into the apk.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had the .wav files on your virtual machine: it is essential you understand that this virutal machine had nothing to do with your apk. All the settings, downloads, uploads (like your wav) etc on this machine are just testing.

You could delete it and nothing really matters. Only your code in your project (if you're using eclipse: the code you see there, so your src, res etc dir's) will go in the apk. NOTHING from the emulator.

Now put them in a folder in your project like @macarse says: `/res/raw`